# Pandas Dataframe timestamp index: localize and replace hours and minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Here my csv raw file:

```
Date,Open
2005-10-03,12.37
2005-10-04,12.5
2005-10-05,13.15
```

I need to transform it to:

```
Date,Open
2005-10-03 09:30:00-04:00,12.37
2005-10-04 09:30:00-04:00,12.5
2005-10-05 09:30:00-04:00,13.15
```

That is:

- Set the hour to 9
- Set the minute to 30
- Set the timezone to US/Eastern

So I am trying:

```
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=1)
df.index=df.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern').
```

Then

```
df.index.minute=30
```

So I am getting:

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

```
df.index.replace(hour=9, minute=30)
```

So I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'

(I also tried with `parse_dates=True` parameter in read_csv function.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the hours/minutes:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df['Date'] += pd.to_timedelta('09:30:00')
```

Output:

```
                       Date   Open
0 2005-10-03 09:30:00-04:00  12.37
1 2005-10-04 09:30:00-04:00  12.50
2 2005-10-05 09:30:00-04:00  13.15
```